# What is Scan-Move?

Tags: starcraft-2

[From wikia](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Scan_Move):

> Scan-Move is a command available to units without an attack, such as
>   high templar and the medivac dropship. The hotkey used is A, the same
>   as the attack command. Using scan-move "orders selected units to move
>   to the target area or follow the target unit. Scan-Moving units will
>   not engage enemies."

I don't understand this description. What's the difference between scan-move and normal move? If I scan-move a high templar ... what will he do when he runs into enemies?

Also, now that I think of it - assume I have a group of units selected, where some have an attack and some don't (e.g. Zealots and High Templars). What actually happens when I hit A-click, and they run into some enemies?

Comment: As far as i know it's just a convenience thing so you can a-move even with units that don't have an attack. I don't know of any difference to normal move but i don't have any sources for either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tooltip for Scan Move:

> Orders selected units to **move** to the target area or **follow** the target unit. Scan-moving units will not engage enemies.

Scan-move **allows the use of auto-cast abilities**. If using a regular move command, the unit will not use auto-cast abilities.

Also note that the default hotkey for both scan-move and attack is "A". If you have a regular unit with an attack, and a unit with scan-move as orders, and you group them together and use the hotkey "A", the game will try to execute the attack first. If that order is successful given, the scan-move is then executed.

E.g. If you have a marauder and medivac in one group, and you use the "a" hotkey and left click on a zealot 
the marauderwill attack the zealot, and the medivac will scan-move to the zealot. If the zealot moves away, the medivac will follow it.

E.g. If you have a marauder and medivac in one group, and you use the "a" hotkey and left click on a mutalisk (remember marauders cannot attack air units), the game will display the error "Must target ground units", and the medivac will not scan-move to the mutalisk.
Here is a list of units, from melee maps, with Scan Move as an ability:

- Warp Prism
- High Templar
- Infestor
- Overlord
- Raven
- Medivac (only this unit has an auto-cast ability)

Comment: I have not tested if units with offensive auto-cast abilities will auto-cast them when being scan-moved.

Comment: what units are those?

Comment: I can't recall if the single player campaign has any of those. I suspect it's unlikely any exist. However it should be possible to create a unit with offensive auto-cast abilities and a scan-move command, from the map/mod editor.

Comment: I wish high templars had psionic storm as an auto cast :(